# knowing Relative path in server

Tags: web-applications, web, client-server, relative-path

### I was learning about what is absolute path and relative path

[image]

I understood about the first three explanations

But i couldnt get the explanation about **`one level up`** for

```
<a href="../page.html">
```

And **`two level up`** for

```
<a href="../../page.html">
```

- How to understand this concept (i:e) `level up` .. Can i get a answer
  to understand what it means in the directory structure.

*Hope i am clear*

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly antiquated thing that goes back to UNIX commands where you would use `cd` to change directories. `cd tips` would move your current working directory to be tips. And `cd ..` would send you back to the parent directory. This UNIX command logically followed to the document driven web. Today you probably should be using root-relative paths only.

Paul Irish has a [great blog post](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) about why you should use root-relative paths.